# yii2 - how to set currency in main config

Tags: yii2, configuration-files, currency, currency-formatting

I need to set currency format as default in config. Now when I change language in frontend the currency is changing too. How can I set it by default

Answer (score 6):

In Config/main.php  eg:

```
'component' => [
      ..........

      'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
        'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
        'decimalSeparator' => ',',
        'thousandSeparator' => ' ',
        'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
        'nullDisplay' => '',          
    ],
```