# Yii2: How to format input number to currency es-AR?

Tags: yii2, currency-formatting

I have a **_form.php** file with this field:

```
<?= 
$form->field($model, 'price')
->textInput([
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'type' => 'number'
])
?>
```

The price has this format `1234.50`. I would like to have the format **es-AR**, like this: `1234,50`.

In the **GridView** of **index.php** I use this code and it works great so I would like to do the same in the **_form** but it is not working.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'price',
    'value' => function($myModel) {
        $myFormat = new NumberFormatter("es-AR", NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
        return  $myFormat->formatCurrency($myModel->price, "ARS");
    },
]
```

Comment: You can set the currencty formatter direcly in main component https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201293/yii2-how-to-set-currency-in-main-config

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do that:

- Add extra class to the price field and use javascript to convert to format you want (remember to return it back on submit)
- Create priceFormat() and use it on AfterFind event and remember to use priceUnFormat() to return to decimal on BeforeSave

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$form->field($model, 'attr', ['inputOptions' => ['value' => Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal($model->attr)]])
```

Comment: Explain your answer